# list of integers to string

Tags: python, string, list

```
a=[2]
a.append(3)
print (a)
```

result is `[2, 3]`.

I want to have a output `23` instead of `[2,3]`. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do something like `a = [2]` in Python, it creates a list out of it with one element `2` in the list.

You seemingly want string operations. There are two ways to do this. Firstly,

```
a = '2'
a = a + '3'
print (a)
```

Another way, probably the one which you're looking for, is converting the list into a string, as follows.

```
a = [2]
a.append(3)
b = ''.join(str(x) for x in a)
print (b)
```

Here is a brief explanation of the second approach:

You forcibly typecast each element of the list `a` to string, and then use `join` method to convert the list to string. Essentially, first the list `[2, 3]` is converted to `['2', '3']` and then `join` is used.

Edit:

Another approach, to better explain what I said above,

```
a = [str(2)]
a.append(str(3))
b = ''.join(a)
print (b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the numbers are stored as ints instead of strings it makes it slightly more difficult as you will need to cast them to strings.

```
a=[2]
a.append(3)
print("".join(str(x) for x in a))
```

This will give your desired output. If you want the output to be an int then you can just cast it back.